# Jquery table addrow plugin how to get the value of the added row

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using the Jquery table addrow plugin to add row dynamically, the code generated is little weird

```
<input name="ctl00$MainPlaceHolder$RecordofNursing1$Licence2" id="MainPlaceHolder_RecordofNursing1_Licence2" type="text" />


<input name="ctl00$MainPlaceHolder$RecordofNursing1$Licence2" id="MainPlaceHolder_RecordofNursing1_Licence2" type="text" />
```

there are two lines with exactly same id, how is that possible? And how can I get data from this dynamical table?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually is a parameter "inputBoxAutoNumber" to make each added row's id difference. 
We can use it like:

```
 $(".addRow").btnAddRow({inputBoxAutoNumber:true});
```